# iOS Programmatically press keyboard button

Tags: ios

Is there anyway to programmatically press a button on the default keyboard for iOS?

For example, after something happens in my app, the keyboard will be visible. I need the program to automatically press or invoke the default action that the space bar would normally do on the keyboard, or the same thing to invoke the Microphone feature of the keyboard.

Is any of this possible?